# Mixture of Type and Non Type parameters to varidic templates

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to pass in a mixture of Type and Non-Type parameters. Like so

```
template<typename ...TAND_NONT> 
class genericTPL { };
```

And then use it like this.

```
genericTPL<5, int, char, 7>
```

And like this

```
template<size_t N, typename ...TAND_NONT> class customTPL { };

template<template<typename...> TT, typename...A> class metaTPL { };

metaTPL<customTPL, A1, A2>  // Note : Compiler errors out saying customTPL doesn't match parameter TT.
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to use a const to type idiom and convert possible acceptable constant to a type and use that type in the varidic args.

Eg:

```
template<size_t N> constToType{}
```

Then I can use constToType<5> and constToType<7> etc. as needed.

Any better ideas of achieving this ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20167869/420683

Comment: Thanks. Looks like wrapping is the only way.